# tlmgr Configured to TinyText (R) Instillation and Not TeX Live 2023

Tags: mactex, tlmgr, tinytex, texlive-2023

I am trying to compile a PDF file from a Jupyter Notebook, but my local LaTeX is having trouble with a particular package. When I go to rectify this problem through the tlmgr command in the Terminal, it says either one of two things:

1. "The repository has a valid signature with expired key" and cannot be accessed for instillation or
2. "The local TeX Live is version 2022 while the remote repository is 2023" and exits the install

No updates through the TexLive Utility seem to have any effect seen in the Terminal or with compiling the Jupyter Notebook, even though it says the missing packages are installed, updated, and the current version is configured to 2023. The $ tlmgr update --all --self command has no effect either, and give the warning above. So far as I can tell, deleting my old TeX Live and re-installing [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) 2023 did not change any outcomes.

Interestingly, I found that tlmgr is configured ($ tlmgr config) to the R package TinyTeX I have installed, but I cannot figure out how to change this nor where to move the tlmgr configuration to. My suspicion is that this R package is interfering with my updated MacTeX install.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to rectify this TeX Live version and command line issue?

Thank you!

Comment: when you type `tlmgr` on the commandline the version that runs is determined by your system path, so you have R's tinytex ahead of your full texlive in your path. presumably if you type latex on the commandline you similarly get the tinytex version. So you need to set your path (sorry can't help with how to do that on macos)

Comment: There were some suggestions online about modifying the configuration, which I did not do since I do not know really what I am doing. $ texconfig conf confirmed what I see in the TeX Live Utility (TeX Live 2023), so I tried deleting the R TinyTex Package (tinytex::uninstall_tinytex() through R). This seems to have resolved the configuration problems for tlmgr in the terminal, at least.